# How do I get rid of oscillation in the signal of a dc circuit that contains a current sensor, conditioned by an op-amp and a low pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, signal, current-measurement, low-pass

As the title says, I have a dc circuit that contains a [current sensor](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/734/MLX91217_Datasheet_Melexis-1578470.pdf), conditioned by a [low pass filter](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX291_MAX296-1513033.pdf). I have a few questions about the circuit and its output.

[image]
[image]
The MAX291 from Maxium Integrated is a low pass filter that includes a built-in opamp. It is Configured as a 2nd-Order Butterworth Lowpass Filter.

The MLX91217 from Melexis is a Hall Effect Current Sensor.

Please take a look at the schematic and tell me if it looks correct. It should follow the three figures presented below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is how do I get rid of oscillation in the output signal.
Below is a chart of four minutes of 1/4 second samples. The current from a 10AMP Heat Gun was applied for 20 seconds across the 2 minute mark. Where does the oscillation come from and how do I git rid of it?

[image]

Comment: The heat gun runs on AC right?

Comment: The schematic is really hard to read/understand as it looks like faint lines connected in a very strange manner. The uncommitted opamp (pins 3 & 4) is running open-loop (really high gain and no filtering) unless you have some hidden lines. Plus, the 8th order LPF isn't connected which begs the question: why aren't you using a regular opamp?

Comment: Connect an oscilloscope to the output of the current sensor. If you don’t have an oscilloscope, use the audio input of your PC along with sound card oscilloscope software. I’d expect you’ll see an AC waveform as you seem to be measuring AC current.  You can probably get away with a simple lowpass in hardware and do the rest of the filtering in your code. You’ll need to rectify the current signal in code anyways.

Comment: Are you using a decoupling capacitor for op-amp? Power Supply unipolar?

Comment: Bryan: Yes, but the heat gun is only applied to the sensor for 20 seconds. The oscillation appears for the entire four minutes of data.

Comment: @qrk I wish I could upload a larger view of the schematic. Thank you for being honest about my skills. Could you be more specific about a few of the strange configurations? If you look at figure four it shows that the chip is configured as a 2nd-Order Butterworth lowpass filter. When stating that it is open-loop are you referring to the main schematic at the top or figure three?

Comment: @Kartman The circuit will, in the end, measure dc current. The reason I am using a heat gun now is just to get a reaction out of the sensor.

Comment: @Antonio51 Can you define a unipolar power supply for me? Referring to figure four, would C1 or C2 be the decoupling capacitor?

Comment: @qrk I added a blowup of the interesting parts of the circuit and turned off the faint lines.

Comment: MAX291 is supplied unipolar, because of the 2 10k resistors with the capacitor 0.1uF (try a little more as 1uF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncommitted opamp LPF looks like this in your schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdI67S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does the above diagram look anything like Figure 4 in the data sheet?

You'll notice that there are zero components between the output of the opamp and the negative input of the opamp. This means the opamp is operating open loop (no negative feedback, which means extremely high gain) which is not a useful configuration for an opamp unless you are trying to emulate an inferior comparator.

Then there's the pseudo-ground using a pair of 10k resistors. Not a good idea unless the part is a micro power part. Better to use an active pseudo-ground or go unipolar since the current sensor output never goes to ground.

Unless you plan to use the main filter (8th order switched capacitor filter) in the MAX291, you are better off using a standard opamp using a Sallen & Key topology which provides a non-inverting LPF function. The circuit in Figure 4 is a Multiple Feedback (MFB) topology which inverts the signal. Inversion of the signal won't work well for a unipolar configuration. The MAX291 uncommitted opamp limits you to only using a MFB topology since the positive input isn't available.

Comment: You have pointed out my error and will now revise and see what happens.

Comment: I am using a unipolar power source. Batteries would be, wouldn't they? Do I not need the 10k divider and caps?

Comment: @TimCerka You are trying to emulate a split supply by using R4 & R5. If you use a Sallen & Key LPF, you may be able to use a single supply configuration since the current sensor output doesn't go to zero volts. To use a Sallen & Key topology you need to use an opamp, not the MAX291. You also need to consider the input voltage range of the analog to digital converter. One other thing, draw your schematic so the signal flows left to right. It's much easier to read since that's the way our forefathers drew schematics.

Comment: Thanks for all your help qrk. I'll be back with a new op-amp [link] (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/AD8571_8572_8574-1502332.pdf) in about a week.